# Log click on "go back" button in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Can you somehow log user click on go back button? I've tried to change `history.go` and `history.back` buttons, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can, you can store `history.length` in local storage, and when user click go back you'll see that the value you store is less than the value in `history.length`.